# The Loop - mixed ASC and DESC order

Tags: loop

I've bought the [Timeline template](http://thdesgn.com/timeline/) that groups the posts by month and order it by DESC. The problem is, that the month must be ordered by DESC and within the month the single posts must be ordered by ASC.

Here is a graphic what I mean:

[image: timeline order]

Here is the loop from the template:

```
<div class="blog-loop clearfix">
<div class="th-timeline-line"></div>
<?php   
    $timeline_position = get_timeline_position();
    $date_old = get_date_old();
?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ; ?>

<?php 
    $date_new = get_the_time("F Y");
    $classes = array(
        'content-post',
    );
    if ( $date_old != $date_new ) { 
        $date_old=$date_new;
        $timeline_position = 'left-column'; ?>
        <h2 class="content-post timeline-date" data-timeline-date="<?php echo esc_html(str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower($date_new) )); ?>" ><?php echo esc_html($date_new); ?></h2>
        <div class="th-timeline-date-line"></div>           
<?php }
    else {
        switch ($timeline_position) {
            case 'left-column':
                $timeline_position='right-column';
                break;
            case 'right-column':
                $timeline_position='left-column';
                break;
        }
    }
    $classes[]=$timeline_position;
?>

<div <?php post_class( $classes ); ?> data-post-id="<?php echo esc_html(str_replace( ' ', '-', strtolower($date_new) )); ?>" data-post-position="<?php echo esc_html($timeline_position);?>">
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" >
<div class="th-timeline-circle"></div>  
<h2 class="post-title">
            <?php if ( ! is_single( get_the_ID() ) ) : ?>
                <a class="appear" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <span class="th-timeline-arrow"></span>
</h2>   

<?php if(has_post_format('gallery')) : ?>

    <?php $images = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_format_gallery_images', true ); ?>

    <?php if($images) : ?>
    <div class="post-img">
        <div class="timeline-gallery_images owl-carousel owl-theme">
            <?php foreach($images as $image) : ?>

                <?php $the_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image, 'full-thumb' ); ?> 
                <?php $thumbn = esc_url($the_image[0]); ?>
                <?php $the_caption = get_post_field('post_excerpt', $image); ?>
                <div class="item"><img src="<?php echo esc_url(aq_resize( $thumbn, 486, 273, true, true )); ?>" <?php if($the_caption) : ?> title="<?php echo esc_html($the_caption); ?>" <?php endif; ?> alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>" /></div>

            <?php endforeach; ?>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php elseif(has_post_format('video')) : ?>
<div class="post-img">
    <div class="post-video embed-responsive-16by9">
        <?php $sp_video = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_format_video_embed', true ); ?>
        <?php if(wp_oembed_get( $sp_video )) : ?>
            <?php echo wp_oembed_get($sp_video); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php echo wp_kses($sp_video, array( 'iframe' => array( 'src' => array(), 'frameborder' => array(), 'allowfullscreen' => array()))); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php elseif(has_post_format('audio')) : ?>

    <div class="post-img audio">
        <?php $sp_audio = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_format_audio_embed', true ); ?>
        <?php if(wp_oembed_get( $sp_audio )) : ?>
            <?php echo wp_oembed_get($sp_audio); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php echo wp_kses($sp_audio, array( 'iframe' => array( 'src' => array(), 'frameborder' => array(), 'auto_play' => array(), 'width' => array(), 'height' => array(), 'scrolling' => array()))); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img class="appear" src="<?php echo timeline_aq_resize( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 486, 273, true, true ); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_title() ); ?>" /></a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?> 

    <div class="blog-wr-meta">
        <div class="post-meta">
            <span class="post-cat"><?php the_category( ' · ' );; ?></span>
            <br />
            <span class="posted-on"><?php echo get_the_date("d. F Y"); ?>   </span> 
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="post-excerpt">
                <?php 
                    $str=get_the_excerpt();
                    echo '<p>'.substr( $str, 0, 130 ).' [...]</p>';
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="post-footer">                   
            <div class="read-more">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" ><?php esc_html_e( 'Weiterlesen', 'th-timeline' ); ?></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="post-counters">
                <li class="irecommendthis-post"><?php if( function_exists('dot_irecommendthis') ) dot_irecommendthis(); ?></li>
                <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && comments_open() ) { ?>                 
                    <li class="comment-post"><?php comments_popup_link( '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>0',  '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>1', '<i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>%'); ?></li>               
                <?php } ?>      
            </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>

    </article>
</div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Is there a way to solve my problem? Thanks to everybody for help.

Comment: Have you tried asking for support from the vendor of the theme?

Comment: Of course, didn't get any response for some days... I've already requested to get my money back... While it will be checked I'll have a try to fix it with you guys :)